# how to split words in a string in c?

Tags: c

I need to build a program that receives up to 30 chars from the user, and then to play with it.
For example, I need to reverses the sentence and then print it, or to rotate it. 
I have been trying to copy the words of the sentence one by one to a matrix of [30][31], but it does not working... any ideas?
I cannot use pointers...
thanks for the help :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main(){
    int i=0,
        j=0,
        wrongData=0,
        charCounter=0,
        word=0,
        letter=0;
    char st[100],
         arr[100]={0},
         mat[30][31]={0};

    printf("Please, enter your sentence >");    
    gets(st);

    while(i<strlen(st)){
        if('A'<=st[i] && st[i]<='Z'){
            charCounter++;
            arr[j] = st[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        } else if(st[i]==' '){
            arr[j] = ' ';
            i++;
            j++;
            while(st[i] == ' '){
                i++;
            }
        } else if(st[i]=='\0'){
            arr[j] = '\0';
            break;
        } else {
            puts("ERROR: Incorrect data, try again.");
            wrongData=1;
            break;
        }

        if(wrongData==0){
            if(charCounter>30){
                puts("ERROR: Incorrect data, try again.");
            }
        }
    }

    puts(st);
    puts(arr);
    if(arr[j]==' '){
        word++;
    }

    while(arr[j]!=' ' && letter<32){
        strcpy(mat[word],arr);
    }

    if(arr[j]=='\0'){
        mat[word][letter]=arr[j];
    }       

    puts(mat[word]);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it's not working? In which way?

Comment: it dosent print what i asked from the matrix... as if i didn't entered the arr to the matrix like i wanted to. or my code for printing isn't right...

Comment: You need to work on learning how to say what you mean and to describe requirements clearly. Below you have begun to explain what you mean by 'reverse' but you have not yet begun to explain what you might mean by 'rotate'. If you can't explain clearly then you make it hard to help you. As far as reversing a sentence goes then you are making this way too complex. Just walk the string backwards and react when you find a space ' ' character. Everything other than a space is part of a word. Grab the words from right to left, push them onto the front of an array (with spaces added) then print them.

Comment: @ron ramon  It is not clear what you mean saying 'to play with it. For example, i need to reverses the sentence and then print it, or to rotate it"

Comment: i mean that i need to take the string from the user, and then to reverses the words in the sentence(string), so the first word will switch with the last word, the second with the one before the last and so on. or in other option to move N words from the start to the end of the sentence. for example if the sentence is "the world is loosing his mind" and the user want to move 3 words, the new sentence will be "loosing his mind the world"

Comment: sorry for my english and my bad explanations and examples, english is not my native language and also i'm new in the programming world...

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account your comment

> the problem is that i need to reverse the words not the letters... for
>   example: if the string is cats hates dogs, i need to get at the end
>   dogs hates cats

then I think you mean something as the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

char * reverse_words( char s[] )
{
    for ( char *p = s, *q = s; *p; p = q )
    {
        while ( isspace( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;

        q = p;

        while ( *q && !isspace( ( unsigned char )*q ) ) ++q;

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < ( q - p ) / 2; i++ )
        {
            char c = p[i];
            p[i] = q[-i-1];
            q[-i-1] = c;
        }
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen( s ); i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n-i-1];
        s[n-i-1] = c;
    }

    return s;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    char s[] = "cats hates dogs";

    puts( s );
    puts( reverse_words( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
cats hates dogs
dogs hates cats
```

Comment: @ronramon The function I showed does not use strtok. As for the function isspace then you can substitute it for direct comparison with space and tab characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. The idea is to go through the string and record the index where each word starts and ends. Then the words can be printed in reverse order afterwards. (btw - it will also be easy to rotate the words).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char st[100] = "here we go again";
  int start[30] = { 0 };
  int end[30] = { 0 };
  int count = 0;
  int len = strlen(st);
  int i, j;


  // Find start and end index of each word
  start[0] = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < len; ++i)
  {
    if (st[i] == ' ')
    {
      end[count] = i;
      ++count;
      start[count] = i + 1;
    }
  }
  end[count] = len;

  // Print the words in reverse order
  for(i=count; i >= 0; --i)
  {
    for (j = start[i]; j < end[i]; ++j)
    {
      printf("%c", st[j]);
    }
    printf(" ");
  }
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

output:

> again go we here

Answer (score 0):

fix your approach like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 30

int main(void){
    int i, j, n, word;
    char st[100], arr[100], mat[MAX_LEN / 2][MAX_LEN + 1];

    printf("Please, enter your sentence (up to %d chars and A-Z or space)\n>", MAX_LEN);fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", st);

    //validate and reduce of spaces
    for(j = i = 0; st[i]; ++i){
        if(i > MAX_LEN){
            fputs("ERROR: Incorrect data, try again.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        if('A'<=st[i] && st[i]<='Z'){
            arr[j++] = st[i];
        } else if(st[i]==' '){
            arr[j++] = ' ';
            while(st[++i] == ' ')//Skip a continuous space
                ;
            --i;//one back for next loop
        } else {
            fputs("ERROR: Incorrect data, try again.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    arr[j] = '\0';//st[i]=='\0' never become true in loop

#if DEBUG
    puts(st);
    puts(arr);
#endif

    //split to word
    for(word = j = i = 0; arr[i];){
        while(arr[i] == ' ')
            ++i;//skip space
        while(arr[i] != ' ' && arr[i] != '\0')
            mat[word][j++] = arr[i++];
        mat[word++][j] = '\0';
        j = 0;
    }
#if DEBUG
    for(i = 0; i < word; ++i)
        puts(mat[i]);
#endif
    puts("reverse word");
    for(i = 0; i < word; ++i){
        if(i)
            putchar(' ');
        printf("%s", mat[word-1-i]);
    }
    puts("\nrotate word");
    printf("Please, enter number of rotate\n>");fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i < word; ++i){
        if(i)
            putchar(' ');
        printf("%s", mat[(i+n)%word]);//rotate left
    }
}
```

Comment: it is very usefull, thank you. and if i need to reverse it first, and later to print it, to continue menipulate it? how do i do it?

Comment: @ronramon You mean like that rotate after reversal? You will be able to actually exchange rather than simply by the index.

Comment: what you gave me was priceless, but i need to reverse and then to print, not to print the reverse...

Comment: So, Position in the array can be changed by the exchange.

Comment: yes. exectly. this is why i thout to spilt the words, get them into matrix, and from there to print them as i want. because later i will have to take the reverse words and continue menipulate them...

Comment: the program that i need to do gets a sentence from the user. it prints it as it is and then the user can choose what he want to do with the sentence. after each choice he makes the sentence changes acording to the choice. for example, the user wrote the sentence, and choose to reverse the order of the words, and after that he decides to move 3 words from the beggining of the sentence to the end of it, the seconed function will take the output of the first, and so on...

Comment: for example, the sentence is "hello my dear beutiful world". after the rotation it will be "world beutiful dear my hello". now i want to move the last to words  to the beggining, and i will get "my hello world beautiful dear".

Comment: I do not know what the problem is. You can as you like.

Comment: what you wrote me prints the words in reverse order, but not changing them for later use... i try to copy them from the matrix in reverse order or to reverse the ordr of them inside the matrix and then print them, but it gives my null